# Find and delete multiple lines parameter values from config section

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I need to delete the value of a parameter from a config file. The problem is that the value has multiple lines with `\n` and there are multiple section in the config file with the same paramenter.
I have something like this

```
[Section1 : Common]

; @label: 

par1 = "va1
val2"

[Section2 : Common]

; @label: 
par1 = "val3"
```

and I need

```
[Section1 : Common]

; @label: 
par1 = ""

[Section2 : Common]

; @label: 
par1 = "val3"
```

Tried using `sed` with no avail

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(par1 ="\).*/\1 ""/' cfg.ini
```

it replaces the first line:

```
[Section1 : Common]

; @label: 
par1 = ""
val2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU sed (version >=4.2.2), you can use the option `-z` that allows capturing more than 1 line:

```
sed -i.bak -z 's/\(\[Section1 : Common\][^[]\+par1 = "\)[^"]\+"/\1"/' file
```

The regex matches the wanted section and the string `par1 =` and replaces the quoted string by an empty one.

Comment: thank you! it works for the first occurrence of `par1` in the file. but i need it to do the replacement in a specific section. Maybe the config file will be updated with new values and parameters in the future. DO you have any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Perl one liner solution:

```
> cat params.txt
[Section1 : Common]

; @label:

par1 = "va1
val2"

[Section2 : Common]

; @label:
par1 = "val3"
> perl -e 'BEGIN{ $x=qx(cat params.txt); $x=~s/\".+?\n.+?\"/\"\"/smg; print "$x";exit } '
[Section1 : Common]

; @label:

par1 = ""

[Section2 : Common]

; @label:
par1 = "val3"
>
```